# Hamcrest assertion fails in Maven test cases

Tags: maven, junit, hamcrest

I am using Hamcrest Matchers to check if two beans have same property Values. It is working fine in Eclipse but fails when I run using cmd. Following is the stack trace for the same. Can anyone please help?

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NONE
        at org.hamcrest.DiagnosingMatcher.matches(DiagnosingMatcher.java:12)
        at org.hamcrest.beans.SamePropertyValuesAs.hasMatchingValues(SamePropertyValuesAs.java:63)
        at org.hamcrest.beans.SamePropertyValuesAs.matchesSafely(SamePropertyValuesAs.java:31)
        at org.hamcrest.TypeSafeDiagnosingMatcher.matches(TypeSafeDiagnosingMatcher.java:55)
        at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:12)
        at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:8)
```

My code is as follows:

```
assertThat(actualBean, samePropertyValuesAs(expectedBean));
```

Comment: Can you show the test and the code of `actualBean`'s class.

Comment: Do you have different versions of Hamcrest in your classpath? See output of `mvn dependency:list -DincludeGroupIds=org.hamcrest`